# Datetime min max issue

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have an excel sheet and I have date columns in that, I read the file and got the data;
Now when I check the data

```
sheets.loc[29000,'Paid Start Date']
```

gives

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 10, 0, 0)
```

but when I try applying datatime module functions it gives error

```
sheets['Paid Start Date'].min()

sheets['Paid Start Date'].max()

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'


sheets['Paid Start Date']

0                   00:00:00
1                   00:00:00
2                   00:00:00
3                   00:00:00
4                   00:00:00
                ...         
29548    2022-11-27 00:00:00
29549    2022-11-27 00:00:00
29550    2022-12-05 00:00:00
29551    2022-12-19 00:00:00
29552    2022-12-20 00:00:00
Name: Paid Start Date, Length: 29553, dtype: object
```

Comment: You have a bunch of times with no dates so how do you wish to compare them with actual dates and times? It's like comparing 12 PM with 24th August 1 PM how do you decide what date to use for the 12 PM?

Comment: I got the answer, I had 0's in some places. In excel they were appearing to be 0/1/19 but it was actually 0 , which was causing issue in all date functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot it got solved.

Comment: try to replace the zeros with null values `sheets.loc[sheets['Paid Start Date']==datetime.time(0,0,0)] = np.nan`

Comment: Consider deleting your question. Or if you think there is value [You Can answer your own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I think it can help any beginner like me who may be facing a problem and may get a solution.